# Preference fragment not opening when i click on settings

Tags: android

I was working on a simple preference fragment example... to do display a preference fragment ...but it is not displaying the preference fragment setting n title bar... it gives a blank !This is what it is showing and not showing the preferences fragment just with title pref fragment mentioned onto it.

MainActivity.java:

```
package com.example.preferencefragments;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


@SuppressLint("NewApi") public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        PrefFragment prefFragment = new PrefFragment();
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(android.R.id.content, prefFragment);
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();


    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

PerfFragment.java:

```
package com.example.preferencefragments;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceFragment;

@SuppressLint("NewApi") public class PrefFragment extends PreferenceFragment
{

    @SuppressLint("NewApi") @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.layout.preferences);
    }

}
```

activitymain.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.preferencefragments.MainActivity" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/setpreference"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Set Preference" 
        />

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/setting_checkbox"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

preferences.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <PreferenceCategory
        android:title="PreferenceCategory A">

        <CheckBoxPreference
            android:key="PREF_CHECKBOX"
            android:title="Title"
            android:summary="Summary" />


    </PreferenceCategory>


</PreferenceScreen>
```

Here is the image:
[enter link description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ehvS4.png)

Comment: Why is the xml settings layout in /layout folder? 

Take a look at the Documentation:

You must save the XML file in the res/xml/ directory. Although you can name the file anything you want, it's traditionally named preferences.xml. You usually need only one file, because branches in the hierarchy (that open their own list of settings) are declared using nested instances of PreferenceScreen.

Answer (score 0):

My guess: you should use `getSupportFragmentManager()` rather than `getFragmentManager()`, as it seems you are using the appcompat-v7 support library.